# What's the best way to upgrade Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I know this question is subjective, but I'll ask:

I've read about various fails during upgrading to the newest version of Ubuntu. (i.e. from Raring to Saucy) That's why I want to know: What is the safest way to upgrade? I've found the following methods:

- `sudo do-release-upgrade`
- Using the provided GUI upgrader (which I guess uses `do-release-upgrade`)
- Burn a DVD/Make a bootstick with the new version and upgrade via installer.

Please add other methods, if there are any. I'd like to have explained answers, and not "Way X is the best!".
Again: I know it's subjective, but I think there are many people with the same question so I think is worth an answer.

PS: I don't want to do a reinstallation.

Comment: My opinion would be to install Ubuntu from a fresh installation, you will cut down any chances of coming up against problems during install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you do a "clean installation", whereby you back up your data, and then install from scratch, and restore your data.

But, since you have already said you don't want to do that, then I suggest you use `sudo do-release-upgrade` from one of the TTYs, which you can get to with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.  Login with your `sudo`-capable user, then do `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

**Like with any OS upgrade, I strongly advise you to back up your critical data that you don't want to lose.** It is possible to lose your data during an upgrade, and you should ALWAYS back up your data.

Comment: I alwaya back up all my data before doing such things... I already experienced a great data loss when replacing WinXP by Win7.

Comment: It's a generic warning I put out there.