# Upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 bug work arround

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 18.04, ppa

Ubuntu 16.04 could not be upgraded to 18.04 due to ppa conflict. I have submitted the [**this issue**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1789056). The comment about this bug is not sufficient to solve this issue, simply, because I could not able to determine which ppa(s) responsible to this issue.

I also unchecked all ppa(s) like the following screen shot

[image]

Is there any suggested solution that allows me to upgrade 16.04 to 18.04?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to upgrade? You can continue to use 16.04 LTS as it is supported. If you really want to upgrade then in your current case - you can change [xenial to bionic manually](https://askubuntu.com/q/1061450/66509). But at first backup your current system.

Comment: @N0rbert I have little problem with new or clean install, indeed, I have no extra empty memory stick to burn an ISO image to it!

Comment: I have the same problem with a certiuficate system I need and it is on ppa, which doesn't allow e to upgrade. Have you find a solution?

Comment: @FabioMarzocca I have never found any solution yet. Now I live with the fact "It is not upgradable system".

Comment: Indeed, they are really too much! Didn't you get the idea about which one is causing the issue?