# Can not upgrade An upgrade from 'eon' to 'bionic' is not supported with this tool

Tags: 18.04, updates, 19.10

When I try to update my Ubuntu 18.04 using Software Updater, I get the following error:

[image: Software Updater error]

> Can not upgrade An upgrade from 'eon' to 'bionic' is not supported
> with this tool.

I didn't find anything related to this on Google or anywhere.

Result of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
```

Output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to

# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-proposed universe multiverse restricted main
```

Comment: You can't. 'Eon' is 19.10, whereas bionic' is 18.04. You can't upgrade backwards from 19.10 to 18.04.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 was tested to upgrade to 18.10 (ie. the next release), and in the future will be tested to upgrade to 20.04 (before 20.04.1 is released; ie. next LTS which is enabled after 20.04.1 is released).  Any other upgrades are untested & unsupported (possible yes, but issues with software packages or other are on you to test & fix). Downgrades are never tested for, & done via re-install. Other upgrade paths can also be accomplished via re-install (I'd use something else, use existing partitions & not format. It'll note packages, erase sys dirs, install, add back packages..)

Comment: @user68186 : I have updated the question.

Comment: @K7AAY: I am getting this by the system. Check the link I have attached.

Comment: @user68186 I am using the default ubuntu update functionality. https://i.imgur.com/Jq0WMZR.png

Comment: Degrade to bionic from eon is not possible. I would suggest to fresh installation of bionic 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I began to run the upgrade and just when I clicked install upgrade, I lost connection to the net. Then this error above persisted.
Although this option is not tested according to the expert, it worked without any glitches, over the other 'half install' Took roughly 2.5 hours.
I am now on 20.4 and its awesome!
Follow these steps as is- using sudo.

```
$ sed -i 's/bionic/focal/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get upgrade
$ apt-get dist-upgrade
$ reboot
```

Comment: Ubuntu's upgrade tool usually hold some packages while upgrading to avoid dependency issues and remove the redundant packages. Although this answer may update 18.04 to 20.04 but would leave some redundant packages. If you're unlucky enough, you'll get into dependency hell. I won't recommend this method on a production machine. Related: [Is editing sources.list a good idea?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1061450/816190)