# Which is the NodeJS default version for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nodejs

Can't find any nodejs package in Ubuntu 20.04 Manifest [here](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.manifest). I'm actually running **nodejs** on Ubuntu 16.04, and planning to Upgrade to Ubuntu 20. Which version should I upgrade to?

Thanks in advande.

Comment: Manifest file contains the pre-installed packages on a fresh installation. For available package, you should search on [Ubuntu Packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com). If your main concern is NodeJS, you can install latest version even in 16.04 and keep that running for another year.

Comment: Thanks @Kulfy. My concern is not about NodeJS, but while upgrading to Ubuntu I was asked to upgrade to 10.19. I was wondering if that's ok or if I had to choose a newer version.

Comment: There is no straight path from 16.04 to 20.04. So how are you upgrading your system? Did you edit `sources.list`?

Comment: Yes. Edited sources to go directly to 20.04. Found some issues that were already addressed, but I was able to upgrade most of the packages.

Comment: Editing sources.list is a very bad idea to upgrade Ubuntu. This may leave your system with lots of obsolete packages and in dependency hell and in the worst case, it may break your system horribly.  See [Is editing sources.list a good idea?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1061450/816190).