# What are the consequences of using codename of a newer Ubuntu release in apt source?

Tags: apt, software-installation, repository, software-sources

If I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver, but I configure *groovy* (20.10) in the apt source, will I have problems installing the software?
If a certain software is installed normally, will there be any risks in the future?

Comment: If I understand what you've described (you didn't say what repositories, nor if you put any package restrictions in place), it'll cause your *bionic* system to upgrade to *groovy* and likely break, as that's not a tested/supported upgrade path, and misses the protections provided by correct *release-upgrade* tools. Your system will also EOL when *groovy* does, ie. also no longer be a LTS release.  It's unwise unless you consider the consequences.

Comment: thanks,If I install the specified software and immediately modify groovy back to bionic, then there will be no other risks?

Comment: That isn't what I said... it'll look for packages that can be updated... and upgrade any *bionic* packages that are found in *groovy* sources (ie. nearly every package you have installed) which is why I said you won't be running *bionic* any longer.  You'll be switching to *groovy* and likely break your system.  Even if you switch sources back to *bionic*, you won't be running *bionic* anymore, but instead a *frankensystem*

Comment: If the package is for example wallpapers for *groovy*, it'll have no *depends* rules that will pull in other *groovy* packages. However most packages will have *depends* rules which cause other packages to be installed, those packages likewise have their own *depends* rules etc... so my last comment is assuming you're after more than say a *groovy* wallpaper package (eg. https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/ubuntu-wallpapers shows one *focal* depends (which really is because *groovy* hasn't had it's wallpapers packaged yet so the quick work-around fix is just to use *focal*'s.. that one is easy

Comment: Related: [Is editing sources.list a good idea?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1061450/816190)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you've described (you didn't say what repositories, nor if you put any package restrictions in place), it'll cause your *bionic* system to upgrade to *groovy* and likely break, as that's not a tested/supported upgrade path, and misses the protections provided by correct *release-upgrade* tools. Your system will also EOL when *groovy* does, ie. also no longer be a LTS release. It's unwise unless you consider the consequences (*research on the packages to be installed, what parts of your software stack will be changed impacting what else you have installed etc*)

*reworded clarification*

Apt & package tools look for packages that can be updated... and upgrade any *bionic* packages that are found in *groovy* sources (ie. nearly every package you have installed) which is why I said you won't be running *bionic* any longer. You'll be switching to *groovy* and likely break your system. Even if you switch sources back to *bionic*, you won't be running *bionic* anymore, but instead a *frankensystem*

If you do the change, `sudo apt update` and then *try* and install only a single package, that may not work either, it'll depend on the package.

If the package is for example wallpapers for *groovy*, it'll have ~no *depends* rules that will pull in other *groovy* packages. However most packages will have *depends* rules which cause other packages to be installed, those packages likewise have their own *depends* rules etc... thus a single package usually pulls in others, the others pulling in more.  (*snowball effect*)

For the *groovy* wallpaper package (eg. https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/ubuntu-wallpapers shows one *focal* depends (which really is because *groovy* hasn't had it's wallpapers packaged yet so the quick work-around fix is just to use *focal*'s.. an easy example).  Most packages however aren't that simple which is the problem.

*this really is just slightly edited comments*

Comment: Anyone asking about the question isn't ready to try things like that in *my opinion*.  If you're capable of accessing or seeing the risks, you're capable of doing the homework & coming to a pretty good conclusion as to the maintenance hurdle & security risks of your decision down the road (ie. it's not just packages installed)....  In the answer I've skipped the maintenance & problems and/or complications the change can cause down the road..